# background image not showing - tailwind

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

Im working with react and tailwind, i using Material tailwind to make a card, so im replacing the `bg-[url("...")]` from material tailwind for my url, and its not working at all

```
<CardHeader
  floated={false}
  shadow={false}
  color='transparent'
  className={`absolute inset-0 m-0 h-full w-full rounded-none bg-[url('${icon}')] bg-cover bg-center`} >
<div className='to-bg-black-10 absolute inset-0 h-full w-full bg-gradient-to-t from-black/80 via-black/50' />
</CardHeader>
```